# How to stroke path in Gimp with single color

Tags: gimp

I'd like to obtain a vertical dashed line with the dashes having a single color. The way I though to go about this is by stroking a rectangle and removing three out of the four sides to obtain a single vertical dashed line.

I did the following:
i.)   `File->New...`
ii.)  Select rectangle
iii.) `Select->To Path`
iv.)  `Edit->Stroke Path...`
v.)   For `Stroke line` select `Pattern`
vi.)  For `Dash preset` select `Normal dots`

The result that I get is shown below. Why does Gimp not use the foreground color only, but creates these weird shades of yellow?

Mode is `RGB color 8-bit gamma integer, GIMP built-in sRGB, 1 layer`

[image]

Comment: At step 5, choose "solid colour" instead.

Comment: Oh wow, that was simple. If you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Just a little note here, it's much easier to add dashed strokes using vector software such as Inkscape (which is also free and open source). GIMP is a photo editor, and not ideal for something like this. In Inkscape you would simply draw a rectangle and set a dashed stroke, you can then easily edit the rectangle, change its size, and the stroke will remain dashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 5 is a mistake.

Choose "Solid colour" instead of "pattern".

If you choose "pattern" it will stroke it with the currently selected pattern in the Patterns dialog.